# How Can I Get Properties of Files in Windows Directories to Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a cockpit spreadsheet for my digital music collection. I managed to get the names of the music files with the following VBA code:

```
Sub DirectoryFileLoop()
Dim fileDirectory As String
Dim fileName As String

fileDirectory = "D:\Sound\Jazz & Blues\"
fileName = Dir(fileDirectory)

i = 2
Do While Len(fileName) > 0
   Range("B" & i).Value = fileName
   i = i + 1
   fileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

However, I also need to get the properties of the files, such as Title, Contributing Artists, Year, etc. For example, the **name** of the file is "Louis Prima - Closer to the Bone.flac", **Title** property is "Closer to the Bone", **Contributing Artists** property is "Louis Prima", **Album** property is "The Call of the Wildest", **Year** property is "1957", **Length** property is "00:04:13" and **Date Modified** property is "20.08.2019 13:22". I can get the **name** with my code, but couldn't find anything to get other properties mentioned. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to read the ID3 tags of the file. Since I'm on my work PC and have no mp3s to test on then I can't give you a working code. But just search for it and you will see how to use the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MVP from MrExcel, Domenic, provided a solution in the link below. I made some adjustments to the code below to display all the properties. You can later specify the columns by put index# to the varColumns that I have commented out.

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/meta-data-of-mp3-and-wav-files-to-excel.1091202/

```
Sub GetMetaDataFromSoundFiles()

    Dim objShellApp As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim varColumns As Variant
    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim fileCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShellApp.Namespace("C:\Your\audio\files\path") 'change the path to the source folder accordingly
    
    'varColumns = Array(0, 20, 21, 28, 16, 14) '  Limit colums to display
    
    ' Make display all
    ReDim varColumns(0 To 321)
    Dim k As Integer
    For k = 0 To 321
        varColumns(k) = k
    Next k
    ' comment out  5 lines above when you uncomment 'varColumns = Array(0, 20, 21, 28, 16, 14).
    
    
    ReDim arrData(0 To UBound(varColumns), 0 To objFolder.Items.Count)
    
    For i = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
        arrData(i, 0) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, varColumns(i))
    Next i
    
    fileCount = 0
    For i = 0 To objFolder.Items.Count - 1
        strFilename = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items.Item(CLng(i)), 0)
        If Right(strFilename, 4) = ".mp3" Or Right(strFilename, 4) = ".wav" Then
            fileCount = fileCount + 1
            For j = 0 To UBound(varColumns)
                arrData(j, fileCount) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items.Item(CLng(i)), varColumns(j))
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrData, 2) + 1, UBound(arrData, 1) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrData)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And thanks Domenic from Mr. Excel as well. This works quite well, the only problem is it runs a little slow since I have too many files, I'll try to improve it and let you know if I can. Other than that, the numbers corresponding to my specified fields are 0, 21, 13, 14, 15, 27, 3, 1.